# Customize how R tmap legend values are printed

Tags: r, tmap

Is there a way to customize how R tmap legend values are printed? Instead of:

[image]

...I want to achieve the following classification in order to avoid printing two times the same value:

248-500 
50**1**-1000 *(501 instead of 500)* 
100**1**-10000 *(1001 instead of 1000)* 
1000**1**-20000 *(10001 instead of 10000)* 
2000**1**-21588 *(20001 instead of 20000)*

Also I would like to print all **"-"** exactly beneath each other so that all tens, hundreds and thousend values are easily comparable. This image illustrates the result I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is my example code which does not yet work:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

mybreaks1 = c(248, 500, 1000, 10000, 20000, 21588) 
mybreaks2 = c()

for (i in 1:length(mybreaks1)-1){
  print(i)
  if (i == 1){
  mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(mybreaks1[i], " - ", mybreaks1[i+1])
  }
  if (i >1){
  mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(mybreaks1[i]+1, " - ", mybreaks1[i+1])
}
}

mybreaks2

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

myplot <- tm_shape(nc) + 
          tm_fill("BIR74",
          palette="Set1", #  tmaptools::palette_explorer()
          style="fixed",
          breaks= mybreaks) + 
          tm_borders(
          col = "grey40", 
          lwd = 1, 
          lty = "solid", 
          alpha = NA) +
          tm_layout(
          legend.show = TRUE,
          frame = FALSE,
          legend.outside = TRUE,
          legend.position = c("right","top")
          #legend.just = "middle", 
          #legend.format=list(fun=function(x) formatC(x, digits=0, format="d"), text.separator= "-", text.align = "left") 
          ) +
          tm_add_legend(labels= mybreaks2,  col = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"))
myplot
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you are including **breaks2** labels in the tm_add_legend() function and not in the tm_fill() function.

I think the following  is what you need:

```
mybreaks1 = c(248, 500, 1000, 10000, 20000, 21588) 
mybreaks2 = c()

for (i in 1:length(mybreaks1)-1){
  print(i)
  if (i == 1){
    mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(mybreaks1[i], " - ", mybreaks1[i+1])
  }
  if (i >1){
    mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(mybreaks1[i]+1, " - ", mybreaks1[i+1])
  }
}

mybreaks2

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

myplot <- tm_shape(nc) + 
  tm_fill("BIR74",
          palette="Set1", #  tmaptools::palette_explorer()
          style="fixed",
          breaks= mybreaks1,
          labels = mybreaks2) + 
  tm_borders(
    col = "grey40", 
    lwd = 1, 
    lty = "solid", 
    alpha = NA) +
  tm_layout(
    legend.show = TRUE,
    frame = FALSE,
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.position = c("right","top"))

myplot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a little on @orlando-sabogal answer - since the question included legend centering and separation of thousands - consider this code:

It uses includes centering of the legend text (the little dashes are not exactly aligned though; you would need a fixed width font for that) and `prettyNum()` is applied to the legend to clearly separate thousands.

Feel free to replace the space if you follow American (and not European) numbering conventions :)

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

mybreaks1 = c(248, 500, 1000, 10000, 20000, 21588) 
mybreaks2 = c()

for (i in 1:length(mybreaks1)-1){
  print(i)
  if (i == 1){
    mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(mybreaks1[i], " - ", mybreaks1[i+1])
  }
  if (i >1){
    mybreaks2[i] <- paste0(prettyNum(mybreaks1[i]+1, big.mark = " "), " - ", prettyNum(mybreaks1[i+1], big.mark = " "))
  }
}

mybreaks2

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

myplot <- tm_shape(nc) + 
  tm_fill("BIR74",
          palette="Set1", #  tmaptools::palette_explorer()
          style="fixed",
          breaks= mybreaks1,
          labels = mybreaks2) + 
  tm_borders(
    col = "grey40", 
    lwd = 1, 
    lty = "solid", 
    alpha = NA) +
  tm_layout(
    legend.show = TRUE,
    frame = FALSE,
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.format = list(text.align = "center"),
    legend.position = c("right","top"))

myplot
```

[image]